# [Codeigniter]Error 404 not found when put 2.0 in folder 1.7

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

I got problem when I use multiple web by put CI 2.0 in the folder that use CI like this

I implement with CI 1.7 as
http://www.domain.com/webci17/webci20
domain.com use normal php code not use framework.
webci17 use CI 1.7 to implement
webci20 use CI 2.0 to implement
I can access to www.domain.com/webci17

but when I acces to
www.domain.com/webci17/webci20

It’s will redirect to 404 not found page
I check by edit index.php in webci20 to any text it’s change display as I change but when change back to default CI index.php it redirect to 404 not found page again.
I'm not sure it involve version of CI but i think not.
Anyone can solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have in your class names this "class Myclass extends CI_Controller"?

Answer (score 0):

By doing this way (if I get your answer correctly) you're telling the CI1.7 installation (which grabs the url and interprets it) to look for a controller named "webci17" and a method called "webci20" (assuming you didn't do any remap). Of course you're getting the 404 not found error.

You surely can have 2 different installation on the same server, even if of different version, but you achieve this by separating the folders (and settings the respective variable), as clearly indicated in the user guide: [managing_apps](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html)

If you're looking to integrate something in your installation, as if it were another CI install, you could take into account using the HMVC implementation [codeigniter modular extension](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) but it's a different story and I higlhy doubt it will work with 2 different versions of CI (many functions have been renamed and/or suppressed in the latest version).

You could, also, try upgrading to the latest version (2.0.2), you can find informations on how to do it in their forum (for. ex, look at [this thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179719/))